# Error in setting Constraints for buttons in Xcode 7 for iPhone6

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios9, size-classes

I have an issue in designing constraints for buttons that support for multiple devices..Actually I have started this Sample app to get used to storyboards where I have used XIB's till now..So please suggest me where Am i going wrong

I have taken a storyboard for iPhone with Compact width and regular height with Simulated metrics of Size a iPhone3.5 inch's as suggested in [Best Simulated metrics for an iOS app which supports all the device version types?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22553?q=best%20simulated)

But my design is not as expected in iPhone 6..Please see the below images and suggest me the best way

[image]

**iPhone 4s**

[image]

**iphone 6**

[image]

Am I using the correct Simulated metrics

[image]

Any Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solved my constraints issue by adjusting view Constraints first as below:

[image]

An than With buttons, Now working fine with all device versions...

[image]